# How to calculate value percentage value between two points

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine

This is probably a really dumb question but..

I have 3 values for example lets call them minX, currentX and maxX. im looking for a way to calculate the percentage of maxX that currentX represents. e.g if maxX is 50 and minX is 40 and currentX is 45 then i want to get 50% this is all pretty basic but the problem im having is when one or more of my variables is a negative number.

Any help would be appreciated, also let me know if i didn't explain myself well enough

Comment: I dont understand what you're asking....

Comment: show the code that you have tried

Comment: Tim's answer works perfectly, but you are right i'll make sure i remember to put up my code next time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(currentX - minX) / (maxX - minX)
```

Will give you the percentage, even if you're using negative numbers (as long as `maxX > currentX > minX`). Also make sure you're dealing with doubles/floats, not ints. otherwise you'll need to cast.

Comment: This is Unity, so it's floats, not doubles.  You can view Unity's implementation of InverseLerp; yours is the important part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some error check in place to ensure it's a positive number.

if (X >= 0)

..do you something

else

Value inputted was less then 0

Comment: Unfortunately these values are being taken from worldspace co-ordinates in Unity3d so sometimes the equation will have to work with negative numbers.

Comment: There's no reason not to accept negative numbers. They're just numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Unity already made the function for you.  Multiply by 100.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mathf.InverseLerp.html